# SAP Sybase IQ 16: Missing DATEROUND()

Tags: datetime, sybaseiq

I'm just wondering what might can be wrong

I was trying to round a date by its quarter. Beside some hacks I found the function DATEROUND, which I was thinking of based of [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?workingSet=IQ16) is able to do so. So I've build up a little test:

```
SELECT DATEROUND(qq, now());
```

which failed with

> Feature 'dateround' not implemented.

Is this a bug inside documentation or did I just miss to enable something? Or is there maybe another easy solution without a case construct for getting this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an answer here I got an idea and solved it for me little different. I needed it inside the column list of an select statement. `$date` is representing the date-column from my table.

```
--SELECT .... 
DATEADD(
    quarter,
    datepart(
        quarter,
        $date)-1,
    dateadd(year,
        datepart(year,
            $date)-1000,
            '1000-01-01 00:00:00')
    )
 --- FROM ....
```

Seems to work by now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the T-SQL compatible `DATEPART` construct to obtain the quarter, and construct the date from that.

For instance using T-SQL on SQL Server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())) + 
    STUFF(
        '00'
        , 3 - (LEN(1+(DATEPART(QUARTER, GETDATE()) * 3) - 3))
        , LEN(1+(DATEPART(QUARTER, GETDATE()) * 3) - 3)
        , 1+(DATEPART(QUARTER, GETDATE()) * 3) - 3
        ) +
    '01');
```

Returns `2015-01-01 00:00:00.000`, the start of the current quarter of 2015.

According to the documentation for Sybase IQ 15; you'd need to modify the above to something like (I can't check the syntax since I don't have Sybase IQ on this machine):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())) + 
    STUFF(
        '00'
        , 3 - (LENGTH(1+(DATEPART(QUARTER, GETDATE()) * 3) - 3))
        , LENGTH(1+(DATEPART(QUARTER, GETDATE()) * 3) - 3)
        , 1+(DATEPART(QUARTER, GETDATE()) * 3) - 3
        ) +
    '01');
```

See http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/X315942.htm for details.

Comment: Just updated the question. It's about the quarter, not the year. So 2015-01-20 becomes 2015-01-01.

Comment: I've modified my answer to reflect your changed question.

Comment: I had some issue with typ conversions which didn't work (inside my final construct). But query gave me an inspiration how I could do it. Thx.